# No audio playback with a specific blendfile on Windows

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I'ver tried Blender 2.79 and 2.78.

I have this really important video to finish and for some weird reason, it's gone silent.
If I use the same blender version with a fresh file, switch to VSE, add a video, audio is no problem. I must overlook something but I can't find what. The system settings seem to be identical.

By the way, if I try to erase one of the strips, Blender unceremoniously closes.

Comment: OK, if I append the scene into a new file, deleting a strip still crashes Blender. Also, Blender 3.1 quits on loading the file. Tiring...

Comment: I have recreated the entire file by now. No idea what the hiccup was.